# How to translate this simple SQL query to NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I wonder how to translate this sql query to use the Criteria API. If not possible or not easy, HQL would be OK

`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 in (1,2,3,4,5,6)`

`(1,2,3,4,5,6)` is an external dynamic array that I set to the query as parameter, it's not a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria();
criteria.Add(Expression.In("Field1", myArray)); //where myArray is the dynamic array you say
criteria.List();
```